# How does StackExchange round a high number of reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was just wondering... How does the rounding work when showing a high reputation such as `14.2K`? Does it round up, down, or from the nearest 5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have between 14,150 and 14,249, inclusive, reputation then you have 14.2k.

Comment: Then when does it consider just `13k` without any decimal? Would that be `12,950` through `13,049`? I assume so since you're at `12,960` and showing `13k`

Comment: PS that wasn't a real question, only to point out that I acknowledge you have a high reputation yourself :D

Comment: Yes, that's correct @JerryDodge.